# How to make a vb.net see a vb 2005 class assembly

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am a java developer that inherited a vb.net web application. This app relies on a VB class assembly that builds in to a dll. I have made some changes to this class assembly but I cant seem to get the vb.net app to pick up the changes. I thought that using regsvr32.exe or regasm.exe would do the trick but after reading a bit more they don't appear to do what I need.

When vb.net uses code such as this import where is it getting the reference to "MyClassName"?

```
<% Import namespace="MyClassName" %>
```

Comment: The existing code uses this class assembly so maybe "reference" is not the right terminology. The webapp does not have an associated project file. Most of the .aspx files are edited in notepad. There must be a config file or registry entry that translates "MyClassName" to c:\mypath\MyClassName.dll.

Answer (score 1):

The reference is not done with Import.
References are set in the virtual project properties. You should see the destination of your reference there.

You need two parts:

1. A reference in project properties
2. An Import of the namespace of your loaded assembly.

A reference could be a reference to an existing project or a reference to an existing dll.

Comment: What would the project properties file be named?

Answer (score 1):

How to: Add or Remove References in Visual Studio:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx

Comment: Future429 - after reading your comment, I think what you're looking for is the @assembly directive, see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d864zc1k.aspx